# In PSTricks thickness of the contour's line of PointSymbol=o

Tags: pstricks

I want to change the thickness of the contour's line of PointSymbol=o in the following line:

```
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol={o},PosAngle=45,PointName=none, , linecolor=red,,linecolor=yellow,dotsize=0.32,](0,0){F}.
```

How can I do this?
Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you expand your code snippet into a small document that can be compiled? That makes it much easier to reproduce the issue and to try possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

With `dotLW` you can *scale*  the current linewidth:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{dotLW}[1]{\def\psk@dotLW{#1 }}
\psset[pstricks]{dotLW=1}
\@namedef{psds@o}{%
  CLW \psk@dotLW mul SLW
  /r2 DS CLW sub def
  \pst@gdot{0 0 DS \tx@SD \pst@usecolor\psfillcolor   0 0 r2 \tx@SD }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o,PosAngle=45,PointName=none](0,0){F}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o,dotscale=3,PosAngle=45,PointName=none](1,1){G}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o,dotscale=3,PosAngle=45,PointName=none, dotsize=5mm](-1,-1){H}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o,dotscale=3,PosAngle=45,PointName=none, dotsize=5mm,dotLW=2](-1,1){H1}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o,dotscale=3,PosAngle=45,PointName=none,dotLW=0.25](1,-1){G1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much!!!!

I have another questions: what is the thickness of the contour's line  when I put dotLW=1? And, without "dotLW", what is the thickness of the contour's line by default for PointSymbol=o?

Thank You!